# How to use columnspan value from an html/xml to generate pdf using xsl fo.(precisely putting the value into xslt stylesheet)

Tags: xslt, pdf, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

hi i would like to use the value of column span(i.e 8) from an html into xsl fo stylesheet where the table cell is defined

below is the html code

```
<tr align="center" style="font-weight: bold">
  <td colspan="8">this is the value</td>
</tr>
```

below is the xslt stylesheet snippet

```
 <fo:table-body>
   <xsl:for-each select="table/tr/td/table/tr">
       <fo:table-row>
         <xsl:for-each select="./*">
           <!--I want the variable to contain number datatype and the value 8-->

           <xsl:variable name="colspan" data-type="number">
             <xsl:value-of select="*/@colspan"/>
           </xsl:variable>
           <xsl:text/>
           <xsl:value-of select="$colspan" />

           <fo:table-cell border-width="0.5pt" border-style="solid" padding="0.5pt" text-align="center" number-columns-spanned="{$colspan}">
             <!-- I want colspan value to be used for spanning if it exist-->
             <fo:block wrap-option="wrap" font-size="6pt">
               <xsl:value-of select="."/>
             </fo:block>
           </fo:table-cell>

           <!--       </xsl:if> -->
         </xsl:for-each>
       </fo:table-row>
     </xsl:for-each>
 </fo:table-body>
```

In short, if a cell spans two columns in HTML, then I want the cell to be spanned in the PDF to be generated using XSL-FO.

Comment: number-columns-spanned can be applied for <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2">.

Answer (score 3):

Use `number-columns-spanned`. It is an attribute of `fo:table-cell`.

For example, test whether the attribute "colspan" is present in the input HTML:

```
<xsl:if test="td/@colspan">
  <fo:table-cell>
    <xsl:attribute name="number-columns-spanned">
      <xsl:value-of select="td/@colspan"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  <!-- Further content-->
  </fo:table-cell>
</xsl:if>
```

See this resource: http://www.schemacentral.com/sc/fo11/e-fo_table-cell.html if you are looking for other attributes of `fo:table-cell`.

If this approach does not produce the wanted results, then the actual problem lies somewhere else. If I had to make a wild guess I'd say that this selection in your code:

```
<xsl:value-of select="*/@colspan"/>
```

Does not retrieve the value of @colspan. In plain English, you are within a `for-each`, looping through all `<td>` elements. Therefore, the above instruction means: "for any child element of a `<td>`, select the value of its colspan attribute". Better:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@colspan"/>
```

Note that there might be other issues with your XSLT code.

Comment: Thanks for your help "@colspan" actually worked ..... /@colspan I was trying but i couldnt get the value ....